# Using jQuery to automate Bootstrap dynamic tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code for a set of dynamic bootstrap tabs:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Me</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">AAA</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">BBB</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">CCC</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <h3><u>Me</u></h3>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3><u>AAA</u></h3>
  <p>content</p>
</div>
<div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3><u>BBB</u></h3>
  <p>content</p>
</div>
<div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3><u>ccc</u></h3>
  <p>content</p>
</div>
```

I want to know if there's a jquery that will automate them after say, 5 seconds to shift to the next tab then revert back to the beginning and loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small script the might give you an idea:

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(function(){
  var content = $(".tab-pane");
  var menu = $(".nav-tabs li");
  var prev = (i%(content.length))-1;
  var curr = i%(content.length);
  if(curr != 0){
    $(menu[prev]).removeClass("active");
    $(menu[curr]).addClass("active");
    $(content[prev]).removeClass("in active");
    $(content[curr]).addClass("in active");
  }else{
    $(menu[menu.length-1]).removeClass("active");
    $(menu[0]).addClass("active");
    $(content[content.length-1]).removeClass("in active");
    $(content[0]).addClass("in active");
  }
  i++;
},1000);
```

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/mt9n1dbs/

Update:

I actually got a better solution for this:

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(function(){
  var menu = $(".nav-tabs li");
  var curr = i%(menu.length);
  if(curr != 0){
    $(".nav-tabs > .active").next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
  }else{
    $(menu[0]).find('a').trigger('click');
  }
  i++;
},1000);
```

Working fiddle 2 : https://jsfiddle.net/mt9n1dbs/1/

Comment: Thanks bud! That's very helpful. Is there a way to get it to fade between the tabs as they change?

Comment: Updated the solution, hope it helps, it also gives you the fade.

Comment: weird, the code working for me here.... which version of jquery are you using?? And are there any console.log errors??

Comment: Hmmm, Im using bootstrap 3.3.6(Its given in the external source in the fiddle...). Is the basic tab change also not working or just the fade?

Comment: Neither with the new code, The normal transition between tabs works fine.

Comment: I dont know where the problem is, but as far as I know the logic works(according to the fiddle 2). It does give you a default fade like when you click normally on a tab. Now my question is, do you want to change the default fade??

Comment: No I'm happy with the fade. I'd just like it to be automated.

Comment: Well Im sorry that I cant help you there, the code for fiddle 2 is working with jquery 2.2.0 and bootstrap 3.3.6, there must be something missing when you tried the new code....

Comment: I'll persevere mate.